# How to use the offset of a string to replace its characters

Tags: string

I have a function named
public static String charencode(int offset, String str){}
If the offset is 1 then all 'a' letters are replaced with 'b', 'b' with 'c', etc.
If the offset is -1 then all 'a' letters are replaced with 'z', 'b' with 'a', etc.

Comment: add language tag and a code sample

Comment: Have you done anything so far? or are you just asking for an implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of [Caesar cipher technique](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/caesar-cipher/). The following can be a solution:

```
public static String charencode(int offset, String str){  
      String result = "";
      if(offset<0)
        offset=26+offset;
      for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
         result+=(char)('a'+(str.charAt(i)-'a'+offset)%26);
      }
      return result;
    }
```

Precondition: String should contain only lowercase letters. 
Here, I used [ASCII values](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) to add offset to a char and find the resulting character.